# How to keep aliases in multiple shell sessions?

Tags: session, shell, alias

I want to set up some alias and would like to keep them so I don't have to reset them every time I have a new Terminal open. How can I do that? Would it require modifying hidden files?

---

EDIT: I'm using Mac, I found a bashrc under /etc, is it the one?

Comment: Do you have `~/.bashrc`? That would be the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your shell/system e.g., for bash on Ubuntu check out `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` files.

Answer (score 1):

Yup – you'll need to put it in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Comment: ~/.profile is not read by bash if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists. Additionally, Terminal can be customized to execute bash without '-l' option therefore profile files won't be read in this case.